# What is the bad in running multiple commands in the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Sql-Server and Postgresql, usually when I need to run multiple commands, I open a new connection, and foreach needed query task I run a command (inserting 1000 rows, for example).

Is it bad if I run multiple query commands in a single command(queries separated by comma) vs previous behavior?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. What does *"what the bad if i run multiple query command in on single command(queries separated by comma)"* mean? Queries can't be separated by commas; that use a semicolon (`;`) as a statement terminator. A query ending in a comma (`,`) would cause an error.

Comment: You cannot run multiple commands per execution, except for *very special* cases in SQL Server (that do not include `INSERT`). You can however, run multiple `INSERT` statements using the same connection, one at a time. You can even batch them.

Comment: @Larnu, yes i mean semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running multiple commands inside a single call (and being able to do it) makes you extremely vulnerable to SQL injections. Any query, even a simple SELECT, becomes dangerous if somebody can append an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement afterwards. That's why many implementations (especially from PHP) simply inhibit the ability of submitting nested queries.

On the other hand, as far as I know, there's almost no valid reason to do so. One usually maintains the connection open, then the overhead implied by the call itself is negligible.

If what you seek is actually **atomicity**, then you want to try "transactions" instead ;

If you worried about the complexity of your queries and don't want to make them be re-parsed at each time, you may take a look to "prepared statements" and stored procedures (or "functions" if you're using a recent version of PostGreSQL).

Comment: First of all, i have a desktop application, using sqlserver 2014 express(SP1), yes  a m using transaction, i have found at one customer having problem, in the same transaction, some row(3 rows of different tables) doesn't updated, i am surprised, but finally with the check and repair command, i found that all the database need to be repaired, one reason is the very bad hardware(CPU Celeron  1.6G, 1G RAM)